# How to solve this problem in DEV C+ percentage calculation?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I've got problem about percentage calculation in DEV C+.

I want to show the program to show the difference in percentage.

Instead of giving the calculated answer, the programs always give me zero.

Here's my code.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <string> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int book1, baht1, book2, baht2, book3, baht3, book4, baht4, ova1, book5, baht5, book6, baht6, book7, baht7, book8, baht8, ova2, Delta, Zeta;

printf("\nPlease enter monthly plan order.");
printf("\n\n\n\nPlease enter the number of 'The Devotion of Suspect X' = ");
scanf("%d", &book1);
baht1 = book1 * 185;
printf("\n\nPlease enter the number of 'Norwegian Wood' = ");
scanf("%d", &book2);
baht2 = book2 * 200;
printf("\n\nPlease enter the number of 'Beautiful World, Where Are You' = ");
scanf("%d", &book3);
baht3 = book3 * 250;
printf("\n\nPlease enter the number of 'Fascism of Love and Fantasy' = ");
scanf("%d", &book4);
baht4 = book4 * 450;
printf("\n\n_____________________________\n");
printf("\n\nPlease enter this month's total sales.");
printf("\n\n\n\nPlease enter the number of 'The Devotion of Suspect X' = ");
scanf("%d", &book5);
baht5 = book5 * 225;
printf("\n\nPlease enter the number of 'Norwegian Wood' = ");
scanf("%d", &book6);
baht6 = book6 * 325;
printf("\n\nPlease enter the number of 'Beautiful World, Where Are You' = ");
scanf("%d", &book7);
baht7 = book7 * 385;
printf("\n\nPlease enter the number of 'Fascism of Love and Fantasy' = ");
scanf("%d", &book8);
baht8 = book8 * 600;
printf("\n\n_____________________________\n");
printf("\n_____________________________\n");
printf("\n\nAlright.");
printf("\n\nLet's see your work.");
ova1 = (baht1 + baht2 + baht3 + baht4);
printf("\n\n\nBudget Price = %d Bahts\n", ova1);
ova2 = (baht5 + baht6 + baht7 + baht8);
printf("\n\nMonthly Sales Price = %d Bahts\n", ova2);
Delta = (ova2 - ova1);
    if (Delta >0)
        printf("\n\n\nYour profit : %d Bahts\n", Delta);
    else
        printf("\n\n\nYour loss : %d Bahts\n", Delta);
        
Zeta = ((Delta)/(ova1) * 100;
    if (Zeta >0)
        printf("\n\nProfit were = %f percents\n", Zeta);
    else
        printf("\n\nLoss were = %f percents\n", Zeta);
return 0;
}
```

Is there's anything wrong about my code?

I'm not good at both English and programming.

Sorry for my broken English and any grammartical incorrect.

Thanks for your help (if there's any).

Answer (score 1):

The primary problem is the type of numbers. The `int` number type is for whole numbers, like 3 and 99. The `int` type does not handle numbers like 3.5 or 0.99. If you try to put a number with a decimal point into an `int`, you will lose the details after the decimal point. That is why you are getting zero. For example, if `Delta=20` and `ova1=50`, then your `Zeta` evaluation goes through these steps:

1. 20/50 * 100;
2. 0 * 100; because you lose the ".4"
3. 0;

One way to improve it is to change the order of the evaluation by doing `Zeta = 100*Delta/ova1;` which does:

1. 100*20/50;
2. 2000/50;
3. 40;

But that is not sufficient, because you will still be losing fractions. The other part of the problem is that `Zeta` should not be an `int`; it should be a `double`, and you need to convert (or "cast") the `int` calculation.

Near the top of your code, remove `Zeta` from the `int` line and add this line below:

```
double Zeta;
```

Then the line to calculate `Zeta` should become:

```
Zeta = (double)100*Delta/ova1;
```